# Calling two methods from two different controls inside a single directive-AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Am new to Angular and i have implemented a directive in my application. The directive has two controls which calls two different controller methods (with parameters). How can i call such functions,as i have understood directives act as plugins ( or sort of).Also the parameter setting is not working also.This is my code

```
myDirective.directive('entityActions', function () {
 return {        
    scope: {
        entity: '=entityActions'
    },
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: [
                  '<td>{{entity.EntityType}}</td>',
                  '<td>{{entity.Description}}</td>',
                  "<td class=''>",
                      "<a onclick='editentity(entity.EntityType)' class='btn btn-info btn-xs margin-right4px'>",
                          "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>",
                      "</a>",
                      "<a onclick='deleteEntity(entity.EntityType)' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>",
                          "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>",
                      "</a>",
                  "</td>"

    ].join('')
 }
});
```

Can anyone please help me

Thanks & Regards
Arjun Menon

Comment: use ng-click instead, assuming your functions are defined in your ctrl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, communications b/w directives and controllers must be done through services/factories.

So let's create a service for the following:

```
.service('EntityService', function() {
    this.editentity = function(type) {}; // define function here instead of controller
    this.deleteEntity = function(type) {}; // define function here instead of controller
});
```

Inject this service inside your existing controller definition:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'EntityService', function($scope, EntityService) {
    $scope.editentity = EntityService.editentity;
    $scope.deletEentity = EntityService.deleteEntity;

}]);
```

Finally, change your directive like this:

```
myDirective.directive('entityActions', function () {
return {        
    scope: {
        entity: '=entityActions'
    },
    restrict: 'EA',
    controller: function($scope, EntityService) {
       $scope.deleteEntity = function(type) {
           EntityService.deleteEntity(type);
       };
       $scope.editentity = function(type) {
           EntityService.editentity(type);
       }
    },
    template: [
                  '<td>{{entity.EntityType}}</td>',
                  '<td>{{entity.Description}}</td>',
                  "<td class=''>",
                      "<a ng-click='editentity(entity.EntityType)' class='btn btn-info btn-xs margin-right4px'>",
                          "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>",
                      "</a>",
                      "<a ng-click='deleteEntity(entity.EntityType)' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>",
                          "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>",
                      "</a>",
                  "</td>"

    ].join('')
}
```

**Note**: Change `onclick` to `ng-click` inside the template.

Comment: Thanks a lot Avijit,Will try and will let you know :)